# installed Ubuntu 16.04 alondside windows 10 on the same partition

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alondside windows 10 on the same partition. Now i cannot access windows, as it boots ubuntu directly.
i cannot find any options to boot to windows, i have no experience with the grub or any options to get windows.
Please help me to solve this as my windows contain very important information, which i don't want to lose.
detail information helps. Thank you

Comment: Usually you select which OS to boot in your BIOS at boot time, of course you may have over written Windows. Run gparted and show us your partitions. To repair grub, run boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Post the url it gives you.

Comment: You cannot install Ubuntu in same partition as Windows as Ubuntu uses ext4 format and Windows uses NTFS. There was the now very old wubi, but that is not supported. From Ubuntu live installer or your install's terminal post this: `sudo parted -l` Running Boot-Repair even better as suggested by bodhi.zazen.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an Ubuntu installation disk booted in its "try before installing" mode and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.